# Fragment in Activity is gets context null in setAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment

this is an issue that I've been having for like a 3 months, actually, since I started to develop this app. I've read hundreds of posts in this web site, in others, I've read tutorials and I haven't found a solution. **I believe this problem has to do something with the way I have the structure of the app**.

I am developing an app that displays several sections, each section is a Fragment, and the main activity uses a ViewPager to display one fragment at a time(like the fb app or the twitter app). Each section will display listviews with different info: news, videos, classifieds, among other stuff. Once a section is displaying, let's say the news section, it shows a listview with the articles/news. The problem is when I try to display the listview, because in the Adapter I use to display the listview gives me NullPointerException, in the line `setAdapter`.

I tracked down the line that gives me the exception, and is actually the `context` declaration. Even though the context is null in all my fragments( I don't know why), I'm able to display the listview, but in some others, the app crashes and gives the the NPE. I get the context through the line `Context context=getActivity()` but when I test this it gives me null.

This is one of the fragments that I've succesfully displayed the listview

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment{
   static ListView newsList;
   static Item item=null;
   Context context=getActivity();
   ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
   List<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
   static int i=0;
   static Activity activity;
   static String HOME_FRAGMENT="NEWS";
   public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE=1;
   FragmentManager fm;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container,false);
   newsList=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.newslist);
   setRetainInstance(true); 
   return view;
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    HomeActivity.activity=activity;
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void displayNews(final List<Item> news){
    try {        
         if(news==null || news.size()==0){
                //Retrieve again the data list
         }
         Log.d("HomeActivity","total news: "+news.size());
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    if(context==null){
         Log.d("HomeActivity","context null!");
    }
    itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(context,(ArrayList<Item>) news);
    newsList.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
}
```

}

UPDATED: And this is another fragment where I get a NPE,

```
public class VideosActivity extends Fragment{

ListView listvideo;
ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
Context context;
Activity activity;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
       View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_activity, container,false);
       listvideo=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.videoslist);
       Log.d("videos activity","onCreateView ready!!");
               context=getActivity();
       setRetainInstance(true); 
       return view;
    }


public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity=activity;
}

public void displayVideos(final List<Item> videos){
    try {        
         if(videos==null || videos.size()==0){
                //Retrieve again the data list

         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    for(int i=0;i<videos.size();i++){

    }
    itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(activity,(ArrayList<Item>) videos);//I also used context in this line, but I still get the NPE
    listvideo.setAdapter(itemAdapter); //Here's the line that gives me the NPE
}
```

}

I am parsing all the info from an XML, and I'm managing everything through AsyncTask
**This is my adapter**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener{
    Item item=new Item();
    private ArrayList<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static final int NO_PICTURE_VIEW=0;
    private static final int PICTURE_VIEW=1;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super();
    news.addAll(items);
    }
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return news.size();
}

    public Item getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getItem(index);
}

    public long getItemId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return index;
}

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
         return 2;
}

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Item article=news.get(position);      
        if(article.getImage()!=null)      
            return PICTURE_VIEW;
        else
                return NO_PICTURE_VIEW;
}
@Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    item=news.get(index);
    int type=getItemViewType(index);
    if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if(type==NO_PICTURE_VIEW){
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_no_picture_list,parent,false);
                TextView titleView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleNoPicture);
        titleView.setText(item.getTitle());
        }
        else{
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_picture_list,parent,false);
        TextView titleView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleArticle);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageItem);
        titleView.setText(item.getTitle());
        image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    }
}

return view;
}
}
```

**This is the main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private String tabs[]={"News","Sports","Valley Life","Videos","Classifieds","Directory","Weather"};
ViewPager viewPager=null;
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    AdapterView adapterView;
static ParseManager parser=new ParseManager();
static List<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
ArrayList<Item> sports=new ArrayList<Item>();
ArrayList<Item> valleyLife=new ArrayList<Item>();
public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE=1;
HomeActivity home;
JSONManager jmanager=new JSONManager();
WeatherManager weather=new WeatherManager();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
                public void onPageSelected(int position)          
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
    });
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterView(fragmentManager));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabs.length);
    adapterView=new AdapterView(getSupportFragmentManager());
    /*initialization of the action bar: color, icon & title.*/
    final android.app.ActionBar actionbar=getActionBar();
    ColorDrawable color=new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#cd853f"));
    actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(color);
    actionbar.setTitle("Title");
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener=new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }   


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //ft.replace(layouts[tab.getPosition()], (adapterView.getItem(tab.getPosition()));
            ft.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  

        }
    };
    /*Displaying Tabs for the app */
    for(int i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)  
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        parser.execute();
        jmanager.execute();
        weather.execute();
        getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**This is my logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.test23.VideosActivity.displayVideos(VideosActivity.java:54)
at com.example.test23.ParseManager.onPostExecute(ParseManager.java:52)
at com.example.test23.ParseManager.onPostExecute(ParseManager.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATE: this is the video_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/videoslist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

I just want to be able to know what's wrong with my app and why I'm getting the context null, so I can proceed with what's next with my app, maybe is something with the structure, the way it's programmed, I don't know. Any help is appreciated, if you need more code, let me know.

Comment: post your videos_activity.xml

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin just posted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to remove the "=getActivity()" from this line:

```
Context context=getActivity();
```

So that it simply reads:

```
Context context;
```

Then change this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle        savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container,false);
   newsList=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.newslist);
   setRetainInstance(true); 
   return view;
}
```

to this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle        savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container,false);
   newsList=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.newslist);
   context = getActivity();  // <--- add this line here
   setRetainInstance(true); 
   return view;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but I still get the NPE, I tested it, but context stills null

Comment: Did you change all of your fragments to use the method above?

Comment: Yes, in all of them, yet I still receiving the NPE

Comment: And the NPE is at which line now?

Comment: same line `listvideo.setAdapter(itemAdapter);`

Comment: Are you sure the itemAdapter is what is null and not listVideo?

Comment: The best I could recommend would be, inside displayVideos(), after itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(...), check that itemAdapter != null, and only set the adapter if it's not null.

Comment: I checked what you said, and it turns out the listview was null, hoerver, I checked the code, id of the listview was correct and everything was fine!! what I noticed is that in my other fragments my listviews are static, so I checged the modifier to static (eg `static ListView listvideo;`) and it worked! I still don't know what happened, but at least I can move on with my app. Thanks =)

Comment: Glad I could be of help!  I always make a habit of checking whether my ListViews are null too, as I've had similar problems in the past.  Also don't forget to upvote or choose a correct answer if they were helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

you can only use `getActivity()` to set context after `onAttach` has been called so do

```
context = getActivity()
```

in your `onCreateView`

Comment: show the updated code and where in the code you are getting the exception